# Android GL ARGB image with GL_BLEND off

Tags: android, opengl-es

When I try to draw an image with alpha channel using OpenGL ES on Android with GL_BLEND disabled, the area that should be transparent is drawn in black...
Who can I choose the color that is used to draw the area that should be transparent

Comment: Is it possible that whatever is behind the image might be black and that the alpha channel is working correctly?

Comment: No the background behind the image is blue, and the thing is Blending is disabled so OpenGL wont blend anything... However the area that should be transparent (if blending was enabled) is drawn in black and I would like to change that colour... I tried glColor4f() but it didnt changed anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color will most likely depend on how the original image is encoded. If your transparent pixels are encoded as rgba(0,0,0,0) you will get black. If you those pixels are encoded as rgba(1,0,0,0) you would get red.